# Is KDE 4.6.X available for Ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: 10.04, kde, kubuntu

I am wondering if KDE 4.6.X is available for the latest LTS version of Ubuntu. I am not sure if it is in the Kubuntu Backports PPA for Lucid, i checked on Launchpad, but was unable to find an entire list of packages for Lucid, so i would like to know if it is possible. Thank you in Advance for any answers provided :)

Answer (score 1):

For what i have seen in the kubuntu forums and ubuntu forums is no. Only the 4.5.x are for 10.04 (Ubuntu/Kubuntu) and 10.10 (Ubuntu/Kubuntu). The 4.6 and newer is for 11.04 (Ubuntu/Kubuntu)

Comment: I know 4.6 is available for Maverick, and that Kubuntu 11.04 ships with 4.6, just wasnt sure if the Backports or anything had been updated for Lucid, but then again, it defeats the purpose of a stable system really.
Thanks for answering :)

Comment: Sorry no backports or anything. Glad to help. Remember to vote answer.

Answer (score 1):

> "I am wondering if KDE 4.6.X is
>   available for the latest LTS version
>   of Ubuntu. "

---

> Latest News and Announcements
>
> ```
> KDE Release 4.6.4
> 1 week 7 hours ago
> Packages for the release of the KDE Software Compilation 4.6.4 are
> ```
>
> available for Kubuntu 11.04...
>       Amarok 2.4.1 "Resolution" Released
>       4 weeks 5 days ago
>       Packages for the release of Amarok 2.4.1 are available for Kubuntu 11.04 and oneiric. Bugs in...
>       KDE Release 4.6.3
>       5 weeks 4 days ago
>       Packages for the release of the KDE Software Compilation 4.6.3 are
>   available for Kubuntu 11.04...

from [kubuntu.org](http://kubuntu.org)

add the following repository to your software sources list:
**ppa:kubuntu-ppa**